# How to scope a condition check to Component or Feature

Tags: wix

I currently have the Condition checks (for properties) under the Package. I have split my MSI into two features that can be installed independently.

Where can I specify the Conditions so that they are checked only when a relevant feature is installed?

```
<Package />
<!-- check only when feature B is installed -->
    <Condition Message="FEATURE_A_PROPERTY variable must be set in the command line">
      Installed OR FEATURE_A_PROPERTY
    </Condition>
<!-- check only when feature B is installed -->
    <Condition Message="FEATURE_B_PROPERTY variable must be set in the command line">
      Installed OR FEATURE_B_PROPERTY
    </Condition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like "launch conditions". Launch conditions are evaluated when the installation starts (aka: launched). Feature selection happens later in your installation process, so launch conditions cannot evaluate them. You can get the desired behavior using an explicit error custom action scheduled after your feature selection.

Comment: This makes sense, tx. Do you have an example for your suggestion? When you say "custom action" do you mean something like a c# (in my case) custom action to which I will provide a list of properties to check or something provided by WIX?

Comment: There is a built in error custom action type. You don't need any procedural code (like C#) to do it. Just declare the error, then schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob Mensching
Solution:

```
        <CustomAction Id='Check_FEATURE_B_VALUE' Error='FEATURE_B_VALUE variable must be set in the command line' />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action='Check_FEATURE_B_VALUE' After='PublishFeatures'>
                <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND &FEATURE_B=3 AND NOT FEATURE_B_VALUE]]>
            </Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```